# calling stored procedure from MVC4 using OledbConnection and return to dataset

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, oracle11g, dataset

I am new to oracle11i, using sql developer to write a procedure to insert data to temporary table - TEMP_ALLOC

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SP_GEN_ALLOC

(A integer, B, Integer, o_cRefCursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)

as
BEGIN
 OPEN o_cRefCursor FOR 
    SELECT colA,colB,colC FROM TEMP_ALLOC;
END SP_GEN_ALLOC;
```

while executing in sql developer, data is getting populated in temporary table, Now I need to call this procedure from class in MVC4.

```
OleDbConnection oConn = new OleDbConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbConn"].ToString());
        try
        {
            oConn.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.Connection = oConn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "SP_GEN_ALLOC";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("A", OleDbType.BigInt).Value = inta;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("B", OleDbType.BigInt).Value = intb;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("o_cRefCursor",OleDbType.xxxxx
            OleDbParameter oraP = new OleDbParameter();                
            oraP.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(oraP);
            OleDbDataReader oreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
              while(oreader.Read())
                  {
                       ///assigning value to model
                  }
```

Here, in OledbParameter, I cannot find OledbType = cursor. Is this the right way to do this?
Please help .. Have been stuck on and googling since two days.
Really appreciate help.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Remove your out parameter because No need to add parameter for OUT's. Read more https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973871.aspx

```
   oConn.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Connection = oConn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "SP_GEN_ALLOC";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("A", OleDbType.BigInt).Value = inta;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("B", OleDbType.BigInt).Value = intb;                      
        OleDbDataReader oreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
          while(oreader.Read())
              {
                   ///assigning value to model
              }
```